# Best way for sharing of domain objects across Eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am making a set of Eclipse Plugins for the Eclipse Workbench.

I want these Eclipse Plugins to communicate with each other through some shared
data structures/managers.

Is there some bootstrapping or other initialization process wherein I
can pass the shared domain objects through the constructor for the plugins(depepndency injection)?

What is the standard and best practice for achieving sharing of data across plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse is OSGi based using the equinox runtime. OSGi manages all of the runtime dependencies you need.
The simplest way is to deploy your common code as a bundle (plugin). Export all of the packages you need to other plugins. (Export-Package header in manifest.mf)
In the plugins you need the package, declare them as imported packages (Import-Package in the manifest.mf file)

If you want to go the extra mile, expose the managers you need as services, and add service consumers in the plugins you need.

Here's a simple tutorial to using services:
http://www.knopflerfish.org/osgi_service_tutorial.html